# How Seal number will be calculated in blockchain hashing?

Tags: hash, blockchain

I'm newbie to blockchain. we use hashing for algorithm for sealed numbers.actually sealed number is identified based on required hashoutput. who will identify these required hashoutput initially.

Comment: what is a sealed number?

Comment: I have gone through this article [link]https://www.creativebloq.com/advice/what-is-blockchain    @JBaczuk there i came across sealed number

Comment: Ok I think i understand the analogy, but what exactly are you asking? Who will identify the required hashoutput? Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

The "sealing number" referred to here is usually called the nonce. In a proof of work blockchain, nodes on the network generally increment the nonce value until they find one with the desired output. The constraint of the output hash is determined by the current chain difficulty. The chain difficulty essentially is used to define an acceptable output hash, and any hash that passes the constraint is accepted and the block can then be published with the nonce as part of the metadata. In Bitcoin the difficulty changes every 2016 blocks and is adjusted up (harder) or down (easier) depending on the time it has taken to publish the last 2016 blocks, versus the ideal time for 2016 blocks (which is 2016 * 10 mins, or approximately 2 weeks) See [this](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty) for more info on difficulty and how it is used in bitcoin.